# Add Angular material to component library

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-6, angular-library

I've added angular material to a component library...well I thought I did!

Everything is working in the test harness (app.module,app.component, etc...)

However when I export my library I get the error

```
Can't resolve '@angular/material'
```

So apparently I haven't added Angular Material where it needs to be added.

Comment: are you trying to use it inside an app when you get that error ? because if that's the case then you just need to install @angular/material inside that app

Comment: Yes, I've imported my component library into an application and receive the error

Comment: yeah so the thing is that @angular-material is a peer dependency of your library module so it doesn't get installed on it's own. Install it inside the app and it should solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `npm install @angular/material --save` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

try with `ng add @angular/material` the guide is available at [angular material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)